# get <textarea> value using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html-parsing

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="80" name="textarea{7}1" class="textarea_getcode">http://example.com/upload/logo.png</textarea>
```

Please tell me how to grab 
http://example.com/upload/logo.png

Thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$textarea = $html->find('textarea[class=textarea_getcode]'); 

$textarea->innertext;
```

something like that?